# How to obtain the transfer function of this sensor?

Tags: sensor

How can I obtain the transfer function(voltage to RH(%)) of [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/192b/0900766b8144ea72.pdf) ratio-metric sensor by using the following data?:

[image]

The Vsupply might drift so I also need to include it in the equation.

Comment: What's wrong with the 31.483 mV/%RH figure in the datasheet snippet?

Comment: It doesnt include the Vsupply and I cannot figure out the proper equation from these. I cannot be sure,

Comment: I have the cal values as in the table, but  mean if the equation is  like (Vout-0.826)/0.0315 for 5V supply. How will it be for 4V supply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was the actual calibration,

RH' = \$\frac {V_{OUT}  (5.00V/V_{SUPPLY}) - 0.826V}{0.315}\$

So for Vsupply = 5.1V, Vout = 0.83V

RH' = (0.83V*(5V/5.1V) - 0.826V)/0.315 = 2.5%  (assuming temperature is 25°C)

However you should also correct for temperature

RH = \$\frac {RH'}{1.0546 – 0.00216T}\$

where T is the temperature in °C

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I also have this issue with this sensor. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511338/trouble-with-using-a-sensor-in-its-recommended-load and opened as another question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The bottom line of the table gives the information you're looking for, I think.

If you're reading this with an ADC and the ADC reference is proportional to V<sub>SUPPLY</sub> then the ratios will remain the same and you should maintain the accuracy of the readings.